# Hibernate: Mapping result set of native query with @SqlResultSetMapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm trying the following:

MyResult.java :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;


@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "myResults", entities = {@EntityResult(entityClass = MyResult.class)})
public class MyResult implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -1934790337160508576L;

    @Column(name="X")
    private int x;

    @Column(name="Y")
    private double y;


    // 
    // Getters and Setters...
    //
}
```

And in other java class:

```
Query q = ((org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl) this.entityManager.createNativeQuery (this.sql,
                        "myResults")).getHibernateQuery ( );
List<MyResult> result = q.list ( );
```

When I run this code I get:

**[PersistenceUnit: MyHibernatePgSql] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory**

And when I remove the: "@Entity" part from the MyResult.java i get:

**org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [myResults]**

I know that I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what? Also I can't find good documentation about this.

Thanks in advance

edit: The query looks like this: `SELECT X, AGG_FUNC(F) AS Y FROM...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks/questions:

- Do you really get only `[PersistenceUnit: MyHibernatePgSql] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory` without any stack trace or log?
- Does your entity have an `@Id` annotation somewhere (required for an entity)?
- Why do you call `getHibernateQuery`? This seems unnecessary and so does the cast into [`o.h.e.QueryImpl`](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/hibernate/api/hibernate-entitymanager/org/hibernate/ejb/QueryImpl.html).
- Why don't you use JPQL (in which case, you could use `SELECT NEW` assuming your entity does have the proper constructor)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The problem was the missing @Id annotation. Rookie mistake :)